# Missing value in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Can someone help me to remove the error?

error "missing value can not be converted to type number." number -1700 from missing value to number

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    open theFile
    tell the first table of the active sheet of document 1
        repeat with i from 2 to the count of rows of column "D"
            set val1 to value of cell i of column "D"
            set the value of cell i of column "D" to val1 * -1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Basically that will happen when a cell doesn't have any value so you must have some empty rows in your table. The easiest thing to do would be to use a try block which will ignore all errors when you can't multiply val1 by -1.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    open theFile
    tell the first table of the active sheet of document 1
        repeat with i from 2 to the count of rows of column "D"
            set val1 to value of cell i of column "D"
            try
                set the value of cell i of column "D" to val1 * -1
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```